# Binding an NSArrayController at runtime

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I need to bind an `NSArrayController's` content set at runtime. The content set is the "many" part of a one:many relation between two `NSManagedObject` classes, for which the one part is known at runtime.

The method to use is (I think):

```
[[self referencesController] bind: <content set> toObject: [self representedObject] withKeyPath: @"references" options: nil]
```

In the above `[self referencesController]` is the `NSArrayController`, `[self representedObject]` is the 1 part of the relationship and `@"references"` is the many part of the relationship.

My question is to what property of NSArrayController do I make the binding, hence what needs to be entered for content set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `@"contentArray"`.